# Hi-light text when audio file playing with corresponding words

Tags: ios4, text-to-speech, iphone

I am developing one iphone application which is include the audio to text conversion.

The requirement is i have an audio file, while playing audio file the need to hi light text with corresponding word audio file.

Please anybody help me out of this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Vulvaji.

Comment: So, what is your exact problem ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: The Exact problem is..... i have an audio file and related images with text. when the audio file playing i need to hi-light text in the image file. still m googling for this but could not find any solution.

Comment: The Exact problem is..... i have an audio file and related images with text. when the audio file playing i need to hi-light text in the image file. still m googling for this but could not find any solution. i have searched so many sites but finding there is no API available in iPhone SDK for this particular functionality. I found one sample code in net (http://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/downloads). but its not helping me to resolve my issue. please help me in this issue.  VULVAJI.